# "Running" an Excel sheet?

Tags: excel-2010

I was sent an Excel workbook.  When I open the book, there is a sheet with some dropdown boxes on it.  Not a "form" per se, but just a regular sheet.  When I click on one of the dropdowns, it gets highlighted like it's ready to be edited, and a new option pops up in my ribbon for "Drawing Tools".  I want to be able to "run" the sheet, so when I click on the dropdown I actually get a dropdown!  I'm somewhat new to Excel 2010.

Comment: If all you are wanting to do is be able to select from the list, then the first step would be to go to you "Developer" tab and make sure the "Design Mode" button is not highlighted.  If it is, then click it to exit design mode.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is Microsoft's document on how to do this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-HP010342141.aspx). It is pretty straight forward. Also, when looking for these issues on the internet it helps to include combobox and make sure to specify the program and version in the search.